# How to get all digits from string regexp ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

How to get all the digits from a sentence string like "Lorem 123 ipsum 456 879" => "123456879" using regexp in ruby?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Just replace everything else.

```
result = subject.gsub(/[^\d]/, '')
```

Comment: You could also use \D for [^\d]...> "Lorem 123 ipsum 456 879".gsub(/\D/, '')
 => "123456879"

Answer (score 9):

Without regex:

```
"Lorem 123 ipsum 456 879".delete('^0-9') #=>"123456879"
```

Comment: The regex `^0-9` means "any character NOT a digit 0 through 9."

In case you were a confused newbie, like me. :}

Answer (score 6):

Ref [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_regular_expressions.htm)

```
result = subject.gsub(/\D/, '')
```

Answer (score 5):

```
"Lorem 123 ipsum 456 879".scan(/\d+/).join # => "123456879"
```

Answer (score 5):

The version from @steenslag is the fastest, thx!

```
require 'benchmark'

class ExtractInt
  def self.v1(string)
    string.gsub(/[^\d]/, '')
  end

  def self.v2(string)
    string.gsub(/\D/, '') 
  end


  def self.v3(string)
    string.delete('^0-9')
  end

  def self.run(m, arg)
    10000.times do 
      self.send(m, arg)
    end
  end
end


Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  x.report('v1') { ExtractInt.run(:v1, 'AAAA4000') }
  x.report('v2') { ExtractInt.run(:v2, 'AAAA4000') }
  x.report('v3') { ExtractInt.run(:v3, 'AAAA4000') }
end


# Rehearsal --------------------------------------
# v1   0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.041564)
# v2   0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.042386)
# v3   0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.011604)
# ----------------------------- total: 0.090000sec

#          user     system      total        real
# v1   0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.042176)
# v2   0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.043753)
# v3   0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.012960)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some correct answers already given, which probably includes what you want to use. A slightly more low-level way:

```
"Lorem 123 ipsum 456 879".chars.select {|c| c =~ /\d/}.join
```

Answer (score 1):

I always thought using the brackets thing was easier to read

```
"nwa240".chars.select {|s| s =~ /[0-9]/}
```

Answer (score 0):

`tr()` is pretty comparable to `delete` performance wise!

```
  ...
  def self.v3(string)
    string.delete('^0-9')
  end

  def self.v4(string)
    string.tr('^0-9', '')
  end

  def self.run(m, arg)
    10000.times do
      self.send(m, arg)
    end
  end
  ...
```

Console:

```
v3   0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.005608)
v4   0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.006141)
```