# Extracting numbers from a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

Consider i have a string like this:

```
"1 hour 7 mins"
```

I need to extract number of `hour` (1) and `min` (7). the problem is either hour or mins can be `nill` so in this case the string would be `1 hour` ot just `7 mins`
I am mostly interested in regular expression. I have already [seen this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019702/how-to-get-all-digits-from-string-regexp-ruby)  and run this code

```
    result = duration.gsub(/[^\d]/, '') 

   result[0]!= nil ? hour=result[0] : hour=0 

   result[1]!=nil ? mins=result[1] : mins=0
```

the problem is, when i have only `5 mins` it gives me 5 and i do not know it is `mins` or `hour`
So how can i do it?

Comment: You can't do that this way

Comment: Could u give me a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you think about something like this:

```
hours = duration.match(/[\d]* hour/).to_s.gsub(/[^\d]/, '')
minutes = duration.match(/[\d]* mins/).to_s.gsub(/[^\d]/, '')
```

Comment: Your way is great, but I think you should put : /(\d*)hours?/ and /(\d*)mins?/

Comment: It would correctly extract even with singular and plural.

Comment: @Oxynum You have a valid point, but there's no need to add the optional `s?`. Remember regex matches anywhere in the string, so `/\d+ min/` should work as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could do that :

```
a = duration[/(\d*)(\s*hour)?s?\s*(\d*)(\s*min)?s?/][0]
if a.include?("hour")
  hour = a[0]
  min = a[2]
else
  min = a[0]
end
```

Improved, this is what I wanted :

```
capture = duration.match(/^((\d*) ?hour)?s? ?((\d*) ?min)?s?/)
hour = capture[2]
min = capture[4]
```

You can try the regex here :
http://rubular.com/r/ACwfzUIHBo

Comment: why such a complex regex?

Comment: Well, I don't know, do you have any improvement suggestion ?

Comment: Oh, I see what I did ^^. My bad, I wanted something simpler, but I got caught in the regex puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't resist a bit of code golf:

You can do:

```
hours,_,mins = (duration.match /^([\d]* h)?([^\d]*)?([\d]* m)?/)[1..3].map(&:to_i)
```

Explanation:

matches number then 'h', then anything not a number, then number then 'm'. Then gets the match data and does .to_i (which in ruby if it starts with a number uses this number). It then assigns 1st and third match to hours and minutes respectively:

Output:

```
2.2.1 :001 > duration = "5 hours 26 min"
 => "5 hours 26 min" 
2.2.1 :002 > hours,_,mins = (duration.match /^([\d]* h)?([^\d]*)?([\d]* m)?/)[1..3].map(&:to_i)
 => [5, 0, 26] 
2.2.1 :003 > hours
 => 5 
2.2.1 :004 > mins
 => 26 
2.2.1 :005 > duration = "5 hours"
 => "5 hours" 
2.2.1 :006 > hours,_,mins = (duration.match /^([\d]* h)?([^\d]*)?([\d]* m)?/)[1..3].map(&:to_i)
 => [5, 0, 0] 
2.2.1 :007 > duration = "54 mins"
 => "54 mins" 
2.2.1 :008 > hours,_,mins = (duration.match /^([\d]* h)?([^\d]*)?([\d]* m)?/)[1..3].map(&:to_i)
 => [0, 0, 54] 
2.2.1 :009 >
```